# Creating % based alerts with elastalert

Tags: elasticsearch, alert, elastalert

Currently with rule type Frequency(or any other), we can configure count based alerts.

ex. if Error=404, occurs more than 5 times in last 1 hour.

But I want to configure % based alerts and not count based alert.

ex. If Error=404 goes beyond 10% in last 1 hour.

Is it possible to configure such alert ?

Answer (score 0):

elastAlert allows anyone to [create their own rules](http://elastalert.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes/adding_rules.html). So you can inspire yourself from what the [frequency rule does](https://github.com/Yelp/elastalert/blob/828e41b0dbff37aa59ea1988e74c49ea0619856a/elastalert/ruletypes.py#L168-L246) and create a new one that works on percentage instead.

In your case, instead of creating a new rule you could simply subclass `FrequencyRule` and modify the behavior to fit your needs